# Sql Query Solution Check

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel stupid asking this question because it seems relatively easy. Okay, I interviewed with a company today and got asked the below SQL query question, I think I provided the right query but the interviewer wasn't impressed at all. I came back to my local system and produced similar data with my query. I cant think of what's wrong with it. What do you all think, is this a wrong solution?
-Thanks for reading this!

**QUESTION:**

Find the total no of products for each store which had more than one block in 2020

| store_id | complaint_day | action_day | product_id | action_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-12-20 | 2020-01-01 | 1A | block |
| 1 | 2019-12-20 | 2020-01-02 | 1A | reinstate |
| 1 | 2019-12-22 | 2020-01-03 | 1A | block |
| 3 | 2019-12-20 | 2020-01-03 | 2B | block |
| 3 | 2019-12-20 | 2020-01-03 | 1A | block |
| 4 | 2019-12-03 | 2020-01-04 | 2C | block |

```
; with cte as
(
select 1 as 'store_id', '2020-01-01' as 'action_day' ,'1A' as product_id, 'block' as 'action_type' Union all
select 1 , '2020-01-01', '1A' , 'reinstate'  Union all
select 1 , '2020-01-02', '1A' , 'block' Union all
select 3 , '2020-01-03', '2B' , 'block' Union all
select 3 , '2020-01-03', '1A' , 'block' Union all
select 4 , '2020-01-04', '2C' , 'block' 
)

Select store_id, count( product_id) as total from cte
where action_type = 'block' and year(action_Day) = 2020
group by store_id
having count(product_id) >1
```

Comment: can you edit the question to add the table structure?

Comment: There you go! added the table

Comment: what do you mean by ```had more than one block```? also, what is the table name? (what is represented by the table?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i understood the question.
You are looking for the number of products on a store with more than 1 block.

```
;with cte as
(
select 1 as 'store_id', '2020-01-01' as 'action_day' ,'1A' as product_id, 'block' as 'action_type' Union all
select 1 , '2020-01-01', '1A' , 'reinstate'  Union all
select 1 , '2020-01-02', '1A' , 'block' Union all
select 3 , '2020-01-03', '2B' , 'block' Union all
select 3 , '2020-01-03', '1A' , 'block' Union all
select 4 , '2020-01-04', '2C' , 'block' 
)

SELECT 
action_type
,product_id
,store_id
,COUNT(1) as block_count
FROM cte
where action_type = 'block' and year(action_Day) = 2020
GROUP BY action_type,product_id,store_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: so products on store 3 should not be on the result because it only have 1 block for each of those products. (1A,2B)